# Routing with regular expressions in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, regex, routes, .net-core, servicestack

I'm trying to build a small .NET Core server with ServiceStack and would like to use regular expressions for routing. So far I've basically just created a Hello World project and connected it to database.

I have these classes in my ServiceModel project:

```
[Route("/hello/{Language}/{Name*}", Matches = @"PathInfo =~ \/hello\/[a-z]{2}\/[A-Za-z]+$")]
public class HelloTo : IReturn<HelloResponse> {
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/hello/{Language*}", Matches = @"PathInfo =~ \/hello\/[a-z]{2}$")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse> {
    public string Language { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse {
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

and this in my ServiceInterface project:

```
public HelloResponse Any(HelloTo request) {
    var greeting = Db.SingleById<Greeting>(request.Language);
    return new HelloResponse { Result = $"{greeting.Text}, {request.Name}!" };
}

public HelloResponse Any(Hello request) {
    var greeting = Db.SingleById<Greeting>(request.Language);
    return new HelloResponse { Result = $"{greeting.Text}, you!" };
}
```

The point is, when I send e.g. this request: `http://localhost/hello/fr`, it goes to the first route, even though it has no *Name* in it.

As far as I can tell, the second route is inaccesible with this configuration. After some experimentation, it seems to me as if the *Matches* parameter is completely ignored, which makes me think that maybe I need to enable something. However, I couldn't find much documentation on this, besides a short note [here](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing) that routing using regexps should be possible somewhat like this.

Note that if I changed the second route from `Route("/hello/{Language*}"` to `Route("/hello/{Language}"`, this sample will work as expected, presumably because routes without wildcards take precedence, but I need routes ending with wildcards like this for it to be of any practical use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was due to Matches rules not being validated for wildcard routes which is now resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/29a6847137c90aa407dc3caef29bf956e2657604) where your example will work as expected from ServiceStack v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Just can't resist the urge to say "Thank you for a quick fix," even though I will probably burn in that one circle of hell that's permanently on fire for a thank you comment.